# dojoConfig can't find script assets when running on IIS

Tags: javascript, dojo, esri

I have the following simplified project structure

```
|
|-app.js
|-components
|  |
|  |-someModule.js
```

my dojoConfig looks like this:

```
dojoConfig = {
     async: true,
     tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
     packages: [{
        name: "components",
        location: '/components'
     }],
     cacheBust: true
};
```

I am loading those files like this:

```
define(["esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
        "esri/map",
        "components/CoordinateTransutils",
        "components/SettingsManager"
    ],
    function(WebMercatorUtils, Map, CoordinateTransUtils, SettingsManager) {

    }
);
```

locally I am developing using nodes `http-server`, which does work fine. Deployed on IIS however I am receiving errors which do look like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
init.js:41 Error: scriptError
    at d (init.js:15)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (init.js:40)
(anonymous) @ init.js:41
init.js:41 src: dojoLoader
init.js:41 info: Array(2)0: "/components/CoordinateTransUtils.js?1496989376094"1: Eventlength: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

The problem at hand is: why is it working on a local dev server, but not on IIS?

Comment: Isn't this typo? In module's require list you have "CoordinateTrans**u**tils" and in error there's "CoordinateTrans**U**tils"

Comment: Yes, this is just a typo.

Comment: What if you ty to configure your packge in dojo like : `packages: [{
        name: "components",
        location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '')+'/components'
     }],`

Comment: @Marco Did you try setting a baseUrl in the dojoConfig?  (i.e. the folder where all your packages are relative to) Otherwise I think everything ends up being relative to dojo.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
var dojoConfig = (function () {
  var base = location.href.split("/");
  base.pop();
  base = base.join("/");
  return {
    async: true,
    isDebug: true,
    packages: [{
      name: "components",
      location: base + "/components"
    }]
  };
})();
```

and it works without problem both locally and on IIS server.

Comment: I had to remove the leading slash before components, to make it work on node and IIS. Now its failing when started via double click from the local filesystem, but that is a draw-back I can live with